# I am trying to make my own Set() method in JavaScript. But getting unexpected output

Tags: javascript, set

I'm kind of wanted to create my own set() method as mySet() for unique element from an array. But getting wrong output.
help me out.

```
let arr = [1,2,3,4,5,2,8,1,3,1]
function mySet(arr){
    let mapObj = {}
    let newArr = []
    for (let i = 0; i <arr.length; i++) {
        if(mapObj[arr[i]]){
           //skip
        }else{
            mapObj[arr[i]]=i
            newArr.push(arr[i])
        }
    }
    return newArr;
}
console.log(mySet(arr)) //i wanted [1,2,3,4,5,8] getting  [1,2,3,4,5,8,1]
```

Comment: You only want first 6 elements ?

Comment: @dineshoz – They are trying to replicate `Set`. They want one instance of each value. In this case that's the first 5 and the 7th.

Answer (score 2):

You need a truthy value for the object in this case, you can use `true`.

The check returns with zero (the first index) the same result as if you have not assigned any value to the property.

```js
function mySet(arr) {
  let mapObj = {}
  let newArr = []
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (!mapObj[arr[i]]) {
      mapObj[arr[i]] = true;
      newArr.push(arr[i])
    }
  }
  return newArr;
}

let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 2, 8, 1, 3, 1]

console.log(mySet(arr));
```

Comment: got it now... thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

`mapObj[arr[i]]=i` assigns the current index.

`if(mapObj[arr[i]]){` treats the value as a boolean.

The first index of the value `1` occurs at `0`.

So you say `mapObj[1] = 0` which is *false*.

You need to assign `true` instead of `i`.

Comment: thanks, man..... now get to know that at i=7 if statement treating it as true.

Comment: @AsimShah — No, at i=7 it is `0` so it adds a second `1` to the array and overrides the `0` with a `7`. Then at `i=9` you hit the third `1` but not the test is against `7` so it doesn't add the third one.